# Home studio setup with Mac & LogicPro

Tags: recording, daw, homerecording, mixer

I used to do recording on a Korg hard disk recorder, worked fine, but due to an intercontinental move, I've left most of my equipment behind as I thought it would be a good time for a modernisation.

I know stack isn't for specific equipment recommendations, therefore I want to ask for a general setup 'architecture.

I currently have: 
- phantom powered mic
- MacBook Pro with LogicPro
- Yamaha digital piano
- istruments such as sax
- acoustic guitar with built in mic

And I want to record: 
- voice/sax (through phantom mic)
- guitar
- piano in MIDI (can do that already through a

My main issue is with connecting the guitar and phantom mic to the MacBook. I have a cheap usb interface, but it doesn't have enough preamp for the guitar to work. This used to work when I routed it through a GTX pedal first with preamp, sadly, did not move that with me.

I used to have a [Behringer mixer](http://media.musiciansfriend.com/is/image/MMGS7/Eurorack-UB1204FX-PRO-Mixer/631234000000000-00-500x500.jpg) and used that to power the mic + connect midi etc. But I didn't move this and I think there are currently better options available, just don't know how they are called.

Would you say I need a DAW or some sort of mixer with USB output?

Comment: When you say "a cheap USB interface" what exactly do you mean? Can you give an exact model number? And when you say "not enough preamp" what do you mean? Did your USB interface have a preamp at all? I'd edit your question to clarify those points for the best answer because the way I'm interpreting your setup ... it should work. So I must be missing something.

Comment: I got the Behringer UCA222, which is reported not to work with guitars.

Comment: Right so it looks like the problem is not that it doesn't have enough preamp gain but that it just doesn't have preamps at all. They are just line inputs. You need preamps for either mics or direct guitar. If you are otherwise happy with this interface you could just add in an external pre (or mixer like you were doing). But most people would probably prefer to pick up an interface that has pres. Here's [an example of what I mean](https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/ScarlettSoloG2), but it's not necessarily a recommendation. You'd want to pick one that fits your needs and read reviews.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My main issue is with connecting the guitar and phantom mic to the MacBook. I have a cheap usb interface, but it doesn't have enough preamp for the guitar to work. This used to work when I routed it through a GTX pedal first with preamp, sadly, did not move that with me.
>
> Would you say I need a DAW or some sort of mixer with USB output

It sounds like you just need a USB (or Thunderbolt) *interface*—not a DAW as that tends to refer to the software or the combination of software and hardware—that has both a phantom powered XLR and an instrument input.

Your Behringer UCA222 only has line inputs and outputs and doesn't include preamps. So either you need to add preamps in front of it—there are standalone ones or you can get another mixer—or you need to get an interface that includes preamps (and at least 1 channel with phantom power).

One benefit of external preamps is that by decoupling them you can decide to get better quality pres if/when your budget allows. When you buy a combined interface you don't get choose because the pres are built-in. But if your budget is tight you probably want an interface because for about the same price as 2 channels of external pres or a small mixer you could just by an entry level 2 channel interface that includes pres. And you could still add in external pres in front of the interface later if you decide you need better quality (it should be absolutely fine for home recording).

You probably don't need an actual mixer though unless you need it for some reason more than the preamps. Or maybe if you want the absolutely cheapest solution and you can find a cheap enough mixer with 2 channels of preamps, one with phantom power. But personally I'd spend the money to get a new combined interface.

Comment: Thanks. Any suggestions on interfaces that would have phantom power and would have at least two tracks?

Comment: You might take a look on the website of a large retailer. One possibility is Thomann.de (you can select English language). Once you have found a  few interfaces you might like, do a google on that interface to see if there are mostly positive reviews or only talk about problems. You might possibly find the interface in a local store at a similar price.

Comment: Thank you. Got a FocusRite in the end. Noticed this question was still open...